# How can I display the splash screen, getSpashScreen always returns null

Tags: javafx-8, splash-screen, netbeans-8

In my small standalone JavaFX app I try to display the splash screen from the initialize method in my controller class:

> ```
>     SplashScreen splash = null;
>     try {
>         splash = SplashScreen.getSplashScreen();
>         if (splash == null) {
>             System.out.println("Splash is null");
>         } else if (!splash.isVisible()) {
>             System.out.println("Splash is NOT visible");
>         } else {
>             System.out.println("Splash is visible");
>             Thread.sleep(3500l);
>         }
>     } catch (UnsupportedOperationException ue) {
>         System.out.println("Spash not supported.");
>     } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
>         System.out.println("Spash sleep interrupted.");
>     } finally {
>         if (splash != null) {
>             splash.close();
>         }
>     }
> ```

It always returns null.
The manifest.mf file:

> Manifest-Version: 1.0 X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added
>   automatically by build SplashScreen-Image: Images/Splash.png
>   Images/Splash.png

When clean and build produces this information:

> Adding splash image reference: src/firemappermetadatatool/Images/Splash.png

I've also edited, following other's recommendations I found when using Google, the project's configuration file adding the path to the Splash.png.

But splash is always null. What am I doing wrong or not doing?

Answer (score 0):

Under Set Configuration->Customize->Run->VM Options I used the wrong base folder for the path to Splash.png.  The correct option is

-splash:src/firemappermetadatatool/Splash.png